# using a regex to grab titles of folders from text file (python)

Tags: python, regex, path, with-statement

I am attempting to use a regex to read through a text file and make a folder in a certain directory based on what the regex finds. The text file I'm reading through is some HTML source code for the page that I wanted to grab titles of folders from. (that's why the regex is searching for an odd value)

[This](http://pastebin.com/geZUY3hB) is the file I'm reading from. (it's super long)

Here is my code:

```
import os
import re
with open('folders.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

  match = re.search(r'>[\w\.-]+</a></td>', lines)
  match = match.rstrip("</a></td>")
  match = match.lstrip(">")
  newpath = r'C:\Desktop\scriptFolders\%s' %match
  if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)
```

When I throw this code into a shell it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 170, in search
  return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

How far off track am I?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a proper HTML parser like beautiful soup?

Comment: use match= re.search(">([^<]*?)</a></td>",lines).group(1)

Comment: Actually, using a HTML parser would help a lot for what I'm doing. I'll take a look at it. I am just trying to grab the names of files on a few web pages, and make a directory for each file name I grab.

Comment: Using groups instead of stripping off the other html tags was useful, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of mistakes in and potential improvements to your code. They're not easy to explain in prose, so here's a working version of the code, with comments highlighting the changes and the reasons behind them.

```
import os
import re

# Precompile the regex so it only happens once. This saves a bit of time,
# especially if your file is large.
# I've also modified the regex to include a capture group [1] for the part
# between the > and the <, allowing us to grab the string there later. There
# are other ways to do it (e.g. with lookbehind and lookahead), but this is the
# simplest.
regex = re.compile(r'>([\w\.-]+)</a></td>')

with open('folders.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # Loop through the lines in f.
    # Alternatively, you can also do
    #     lines = f.readlines()
    #     for line in lines:
    #         ...
    # but it's less memory-efficient because it puts the whole file in memory.
    for line in f:
        match = regex.search(line)
        # re.search returns a match object [2], or None if the string doesn't
        # match the regex.
        if not match:  # Throw away non-matching lines.
            continue
        # Get the value of capture group #1.
        match = match.group(1)
        newpath = r'C:\Desktop\scriptFolders\%s' % match
        if not os.path.exists(newpath):
            os.makedirs(newpath)
```

References:

1. [Capture groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group)
2. [Match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I really should have looked more into the API before posting anything, but this will be really useful for the next time I need to write a regex. Thanks again!